# Installing Jest with NPM

Tags: node.js, jestjs, npm-install

I have these WARNings in console when I try to install Jest, I already tried installing Node and Jest again but it doesn't work.

```
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are warning messages not error messages. It shows some dependencies have deprecation which is not your problem but their abstractions. You can just ignore the message. But if you also getting runtime errors then share it